# How to connect with iPhone using Nautilus?

Tags: ssh, iphone

I'm new to Linux, and Ubuntu as well.

I want to sync my iPhone. I tried with Rhythmbox and Amarok, but neither worked. So now I'm trying to sync over WiFi using SSH.

I got open SSH and SBSettings on my iPhone, I can also connect to it using terminal and command

```
ssh [IP address] -l root
```

My problem is the nautilus interface; when I go to files --> enter location, I can't find the port number, IP address etc, all I get is a window with the command `smb://`.

And even using smb, I still cant add the iPhone as a network place, I get a message that the connection timed out.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to connect using the Fillezilla FTP client. I don't know why, but I simply can't access via SSH using Nautilus, and after racking my brains for a solution to the issue, I decided to go with the simple solution.

Comment: As you're a low reputation user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Answer (score 1):

Click on *File*, do you see *Connect to Server*? If so, click on that. A small window will appear.

You can choose "Type" (drop-down menu, choose *SSH* and *Port* will automatically change to 22 which is the default SSH port).

Then enter your username and password in the *User name* and *Password* fields and hit *Connect*.

In *Server*, enter your iPhone's IP address.

To get your iPhone IP address, I assume you are connected to your WiFi router. On your iPhone, you go to *Settings*, then click on *WiFi* and the name of the network you're connected to.

You should see your iPhone's IP address, which you type into *Server* on your computer.